# MongoDB efficient way of writing a query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I need to search for a document based on 3 conditions in a particular order.

i.e consider my documents has attributes like a user, Due date, and department.

I need to see if any document is there for a particular user ID, if not then I need to check any document having today as the due date if not I need to find a document having the particular department.

Please suggest me how can I do this in an efficient way in MongoDB query with a minimal DB hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **$or** operator in Mongo has a short circuit behavior, meaning that it'll return true as soon as one of the conditions is valid, they have good examples on their official [Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/or/).
Basically :

```
db.mycollection.find({$or : [{condition1},{condition2},{condition3}]})
```

If condition1 is true then it matches your document.

If condition1 is false, then Mongo will check condition2 to see if it matches.

If condition1 and condition2 are false, then Mongo will run condition3 and so on and so forth...

Does this answer your question ?

Comment: But if in my collection there are data which matches both condition1 and condition2, then my query should return only those documents which satisfy condition1.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood your question, if that's the case then as far as I know you have to run the queries separately as you need the actual result before you know if you have to run the other ones.